# mongodb 'document' variable define in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, mongodb, php-mongodb

I am using **Codeigniter** with **PHP**.
We can define empty array for **mongodb** query like following,

```
$db->user->insert(array('report'=> array()));
```

How i can define empty `document`(datatype) for mongodb in PHP`?`

Here i know, i can create the `document` variable when using another run time query (using **$set** or else). But i need to create `document` variable, when i `insert`.

If i create document variable like following,

```
$a = array();
$db->user->insert(array('report'=> $a));
```

following code is not working,

```
$db->user->update(
    array('user' => $user ), 
    array('$set' => array(
        'report.' . $number => 
             array('id'=>$number, 'on' => time(), 'status'=> 0)
    )));
```

here, `$number` is string variable.

Comment: Do you mean a field in your document called `document`?

Comment: @Sammaye `document` is a database field type in MongoDB

Comment: What happens if you pass along an empty array() as in your example? This should work and store an empty document.

Comment: @SaschaM78 It is? Have you got a page explaining a Document field type?

Comment: @Sammaye [BSON documents, MongoDB docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/)

Comment: @SaschaM78 That is a full BSON document not a field type (same as a row in SQL) or even a datatype, you cannot make a new empty BSON document unless you have a capped collection whereby you have muted the `_id`. You can of course enter a new document without any other fields other than `_id` by setting an empty array.

Comment: @SaschaM78 That: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-bson-types is actually the list of types that BSON Documents support.

Comment: @SaschaM78 if i add as array, i cant insert($set) the document.

Comment: @Sammaye thanks a lot for the reference! As mentioned in chat, I interpreted document as BSON document so sorry for getting you wrong.

Comment: i really suggest you this https://github.com/alexbilbie/codeigniter-mongodb-library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Finally* no way for my question. I searched in many way. So, We can create the `document` variable when using another run time query (using **$set** or else). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The MongoDB PHP driver supports sending in empty objects (it has no validation on it's end to make sure you send something of value) to be saved but detecting that this method of saving objects would be useless without knowing the `_id` of the object you have just saved you can do:

```
$a = array();
$db->user->insert($a);
var_dump($a['_id']);
```

Since if passed a variable, the insert function for MongoDB will modify (by reference) the original variable and add the `_id` field to it.

You cannot save a "empty" object however (an object without the immutable `_id`) to a normal collection. This of course differs for things like capped collections.

Comment: So What? What you meant by brackets?

Comment: @KarSho Yea so where you see 3 brackets on the last line of your edit there is only supposed to be two. Can you show us an example doc of what your updating and and can you tell us what `$user` is? Are you sure this actually finds a doc?